# how to implemet POSIX select() based behaviour, within boost::asio

Tags: c++

I've already wasted two days reading documentation of boost::asio
And I still don't know how I could implement blocking `select()` like function for several sockets using only one thread (using boost framework).
Asynchronous functions of boost::asio return immediately, so there would be a need to put some wait function in main thread until one of the `async_read`'s finishes.
I suspect that this would time consuming, but I'm really restricted by performance requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `io_service` object is an abstraction of the `select` function. Set up your sockets and then call the `io_service::run` member function from your main thread. The `io_service::run` function will block until all of the work associated with the `io_service` instance is completed. You can schedule more work in your asynchronous handlers.

You can also use `io_service::run_one`, `io_service::poll`, or `io_service::poll_one` in place of `io_service::run`.