# N-party client-to-client communication using C++ and Boost::Asio

Tags: c++, unix, network-programming, boost-asio

I've been playing around with Boost::Asio and checking out it's capability when it comes to n independent users collaborating to compute a function on shared inputs.

At one point I need to get each user to send to (resp. receive from) all the other users some data.

I guess effectively I'm looking for "active" establishment by each user opposed to the common client-server examples seen all over the internet.

I've got working code that allows a user to send data to another user. I'm having trouble seeing how I should get all users to be simultaneously sending and receiving from each other. I also can't seem to generalise multiple `async_connects` at once.

Are there any suggestions as to how this sort of protocol should be implemented? Should I be looking at using threads to manage both sending and receiving?

Answer (score -1):

If you on Unix-based OS, such as Linux, I would start with much less complex solution using `C` programming language (or `C++` if you need that), but without using `Boost` library. Just use plain old `select` syscall instead. See [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) and [tutorial manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select_tut).

Only after that I'd switch to something fancy like `Boost`.

See also [this tutorial](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) about BSD sockets programming.

Comment: I don't have any experience with asio so I wouldn't consider this an official answer, but I think that Victor might be on the right track with select-like functionality. Here's something that looks related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910064/how-to-implemet-posix-select-based-behaviour-within-boostasio